# jquery onclick parent remove child action

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually I'm really very sorry about my question, I'm not sure how to make attention or ask question about this kind of problem.

Please see my code 1st.

```
<div data-model="ABC123" id="product">Select a Product</div>
<ul id="lists">
  <li data-product="P1">Product 1
    <ul id="sublists">
      <li data-item="it1">P1 Item 1</li>
      <li data-item="it2">P1 Item 2</li>
      <li data-item="it3">P1 Item 3</li>
      <li data-item="it4">P1 Item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-product="P2">Product 2
      <ul>
      <li data-item="it1">P2 Item 1</li>
      <li data-item="it2">P2 Item 2</li>
      <li data-item="it3">P2 Item 3</li>
      <li data-item="it4">P2 Item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-product="P3">Product 3</li>
  <li data-product="P4">Product 4</li>
</ul>
<div id="codes">
  <span class="code1"></span>
  <span class="code2"></span>
  <span class="code3"></span>
</div>
```

The jquery code is:

```
<script>$('#product').click(function () {
  var pmodel = $(this).data('model');
  $('.code1').empty().append(pmodel);
  $('.code2').empty();
  $('.code3').empty();
});
$('#lists li').click(function () {
  var dmodel = $(this).data('product');
  $('.code2').empty().append(dmodel);
});
$('#lists li ul li').click(function () {
  var item = $(this).data('item');
  $('.code3').empty().append(item);
});</script>
```

You may directly view this at http://codepen.io/alshedupur/pen/YqKGqV

Everything is work fine, but my problem is, when I trigger parent list item like: Product 1 / Product 2 / Product 3

In result I want to empty `.code3` `span`

I try to use `$('.code3').empty();` on 2nd action but if I use this, then 3rd action I mean sub list click function not work.

Please see my screenshot for clearly understand what I want: [image: help]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to empty `.code3` as well.

```js
$('#product').click(function() {
  var pmodel = $(this).data('model');
  $('.code1').empty().append(pmodel);
  $('.code2').empty();
  $('.code3').empty();
});
$('#lists > li').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var dmodel = $(this).data('product');
  $('.code2').empty().append(dmodel);
  $('.code3').empty();
});

$('#lists li ul li').click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
  var item = $(this).data('item');
  var dmodel = $(this).parents("li").data('product');
  $('.code2').empty().append(dmodel);
  $('.code3').empty().append(item);
});
```

```css
#product:hover,
li:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-model="ABC123" id="product">Select a Product</div>
<ul id="lists">
  <li data-product="P1">Product 1
    <ul id="sublists">
      <li data-item="it1">P1 Item 1</li>
      <li data-item="it2">P1 Item 2</li>
      <li data-item="it3">P1 Item 3</li>
      <li data-item="it4">P1 Item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-product="P2">Product 2
    <ul>
      <li data-item="it1">P2 Item 1</li>
      <li data-item="it2">P2 Item 2</li>
      <li data-item="it3">P2 Item 3</li>
      <li data-item="it4">P2 Item 4</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-product="P3">Product 3</li>
  <li data-product="P4">Product 4</li>
</ul>
<div id="codes">
  <span class="code1"></span>
  <span class="code2"></span>
  <span class="code3"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: When you select the child as first, do you want to display his parent directly?

Comment: I think you want to display the parents too after selecting the child first. Otherwise it is possible to display product 4 with a child of product 2. let me know if you want to fix this.

Comment: Yes I want to display parent after selecting child, but after selecting parent, I want to hide child. Anyway Your code is now work well.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It was an easy job to do for me, so I updated the code.

Comment: WOW ! That's Cool! Thanks a lot for update. If there was an system to vote up 10 times, I'll did it for you :) You are really a genius .